# Django templates: optimizing the update of a template

Tags: django, django-templates

A noob question to be sure. I have a template that has several moving parts and I'm looking for direction on the best way to structure this django `response`.

Consider the template like this:

`<div>` Display results of complex_calculation_1 + a `button` to update the data for this div `<\div>`

`<div>` Display results of complex_calculation_2 + a `button` to update the data for this div `<\div>`

`<div>` Display results of complex_calculation_3 + a `button` to update the data for this div `<\div>`

`<div>` Display results of complex_calculation_4 + a `button` to update the whole page `<\div>`

The output of each calculation is easily saved. Currently, every time a `button` is pushed, I re-calculate the particular calculation then re-render the whole page which causes many `forloop` iterations in all of the parts.

I would like to be able to cache each part of the template in an optimal manner (what would that be?), provide a `response` which updates only the part of the page which needs to be updated and renders the updated page appropriately.

So my question is: how should I proceed to handle this in a manner which would create the greatest efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jquery` and `ajax` to update just the specific part of your template, suppose:

```
<div>
    <span id="data_1"> Display results of complex_calculation_1 + </span>
    <button class="data_btn" span_id="data_1">Update</button>
<\div>

<script>
 $('.data_btn').click(function(){
    // send post data which you need in `data` variable
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'url_name_for_your_view_here' %}',
        data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response) {
            $($(this).attr('span_id')).text(response.data);
            //where response.data is the data which you want to display
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
            alert(rs.responseText);
            alert('Oops! something went worng..');
         }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So if I originally included `'data1':data1` in my context dictionary, this script updates data1, but how does it update the html without calling the associated view? I guess what I am asking is what does `function(response)` do in this script?

Comment: @Cole please understand how ajax works with django. Read some tutorial. Check [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/31/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-1/) tutorial then you will understand the snippet i posted.

Comment: Check the `url` variable it is actually calling the associated view in which you have to replace `url_name_for_your_view_here` with valid url name. Then your view is going to return something back so `success` function is the `CallBack` which will take response from your view. And update what you needs to update in the html in a `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume, that site visitor has JavaScript enabled, you could use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),
to send your data, perform calculations in separate view and post it back to your site - that way the whole page won't be reloaded, and it will look very elegant.

Of course, any visitor should be able to use your site even if his browser doesn't support JavaScript, but then, if it's only minority of visitors, then I wouldn't bother optimizing it for these rare cases, just leaving it as it is.

I'm not sure about caching mechanisms in Django, so I won't propose anything if you really can't rely on Ajax.